# Issues while schema conversion from DB2 to SQL using SSMA

Tags: sql, db2, database-migration

I've downloaded SSMA for DB2 V8.2.0. I kept all the default setting and tried to convert couple of Stored procs from DB2 to SQL 2017.

I've selected one SP and clcik on convert Schema and I got special characters just like below.

%@@@@�������@�������

%@@@@�������@����@��

%@@@@������@�

%@@@@������������@���

%@@@@�����������@��������@������@������

Do I have to change any setting? Why is this happening?

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?  Looks like an EBCDIC to ASCII issue...

Comment: Hi Charles...It says  DSN12010 When I run    `SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;`. what is EBCDIC to ASCII issue and how do I resolve it?